# How can I make the player continue floating from the spot where I paused it from?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my player float up and down but pause when I hold click. Upon releasing left click, I want to make the player continue floating from that same position. So far my code can do all of that except make the player continue floating from the position that it was stopped at. Instead, the player stops but then continues floating from where it would be if I hadn't stopped it in the first place.

```
        public float amplitude = 0.5f;
        public float frequency = 1f;

        void Start()
        {
            rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            // Store the starting position & rotation of the object
            posOffset = transform.position;
            isClick = false;
        }
        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                isClick = true;
            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {
                isClick = false;
            }

            if (isClick)
            {
                rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionY;
                curPos = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position;
            }


            if (!isClick)
            {

                tempPos = posOffset;
                tempPos.y = Mathf.Sin(Time.fixedTime * Mathf.PI * frequency) * amplitude;


                transform.position = tempPos;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you pause the game or the movement? Pausing the game usually means skipping the Fixed Updates for a while. Basically pausing the game ticks. Not actually changing any game state values.

Comment: Are you missing a line here? is this all happening in update?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using the

```
Time.timeScale = 0;
```

But be aware that this will stop the Time.deltaTime, but you could use insetead Time.fixedDeltaTime;

Check the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html)

Comment: This will effectively pause the entire game?

Comment: Yes, it will pause every class that uses Time. You could also assign the scale to a different value to make it run faster or slower, f.e. 0.5f (half the speed) or 2f (double speed)